# How can I Display previous 4 value excluding current value in python?

Tags: python, modulo

Basically I have digits ranging from 1-12 with corresponding values. How can I display the output as b,a,l and k if user enters 3?

```
mm=int(raw_input("enter a number"))
ans = {
    "1":"a",
    "2":"b",
    "3":"c",
    "4":"d",
    "5":"e",
    "6":"f",
    "7":"g",
    "8":"h",
    "9":"i",
    "10":"j",
    "11":"k",
    "12":"l"
}
v=(mm-1)%12 
w=(mm-2)%12 
x=(mm-3)%12 
y= (mm-4)%12 

print ans[str(v)] 
print ans[str(w)] 
print ans[str(x)] 
print ans[str(y)]
```

I will be helpful if anyone helps me out using this code or any other alternate way.

Comment: So what is the issue with above code?

Comment: What do you get now?

Comment: The issue is when the value gets 3-3 its 0 so its not working. Gives, keyError '0' I wan't it as, if it gets 0, get to the value 12.

Comment: Tip: you can use integers as keys for dictionaries: no need to use strings, just use `1`, `2` etc as keys. Also, consider using the `chr` builtin function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will change it next time. But, could you please solve this issue.

Comment: Most straightforward solution: add an if-statement to test for v, w, x or y being 0. Other solution: redefine your dictionary (e.g., put in an extra element {"0": "l"}).

Comment: isn't there any other short solution. Also if user enters value 1, then it should have output l,k,j,i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use lists instead of dictionnaries, I’d go with

```
def get_ans(index):
    ans = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]
    end = index - 1
    start = end - 4
    if start < 0:
        result = ans[start:] + ans[:end]
    else:
        result = ans[start:end]
    print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mm=int(raw_input("enter a number "))
    get_ans(mm)
```

If you can't use lists directly, I’d suggest using `range` to generate the 4 integers you need and lookup their value into your dictionnary.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. Cheers (y)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want to do?

```
mm = 1

def ans(i):
    i = (i+1)%12
    return chr(i+97)

def get_answer_list(i):
    return [ans((i-1)%12), ans((i-2)%12),ans((i-3)%12),ans((i-4)%12)]

print( get_answer_list(mm) )
```

this could then be simplified to

```
mm = 1

def ans(i):
    return chr(i+97)

def get_answer_list(i):
    return [ans(i%12), ans((i-1)%12),ans((i-2)%12),ans((i-3)%12)]

print( get_answer_list(mm) )
```

Comment: Thank You, but it displays only of characters, I need to display it from a list of 'n' strings.

Comment: you should update your variable name in `get_answer_list` as well (`nm -> i`)